# IP address lost after rebooting Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

I have configured IP in desktop version of ubuntu server and I access that server through VNC viewer. But when I reboot the server the IP address gets flushed and I am not able to access the server through VNC Viewer.

Why does the IP get flushed every-time I reboot it?

Is there a specific command we have enter to make it permanent so that it does not gets flush after rebooting the server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit /etc/network/interfaces

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and change

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

to

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.50
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Obviously replacing the addresses with those that are relevant to your site.

You may also need to edit /etc/resolv.conf to configure name resolution

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

and add

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```